# Android SQLite Storage usage

Tags: android, sqlite

Im using SQLite Storage in my healthcare application.I have some idea of why we are going for local storage

1. No need of internet connection.
2. individual Data.
3. Fast to load.
4. if we want can take a dump of db in server and can be retrieved.

But, I got some opposite question like

suppose if i lost my phone there is chance to get my personal data from the memory of the device.

kindly help me

Comment: Are there any other concerns beside that?

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the data from SQLite. Either encrypt it on runtime using a custom encryption algorithm, or you can use some APIs for that. The most popular seems to be [`SQLCipher for Android`](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/).

Comment: yes i hope this ll work.i have one more doubt.already i have created a project with database.do you have any idea on integrating the SQLchiper on to it?

Comment: Beside `"Read the documentation, understand how it works and apply that to your DAO logic"` ... no :)